# Getting error in GitHub: Port: 443 connection timed out

Tags: github

The error:

```
Git clone  -b main 'https://GitHub.com/username-prog (any type of username)/.git (folder)/
Failed to connect to github.com port 443: Connection timed out
```

How was the problem solved? I tried:

```
Git config --global --unset https.proxy .
```

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure to use `https://github.com/...` (not `https://GitHub.com/`").

Second, check your environment variables (like `HTTP_PROXY`/`HTTPS_PROXY`): unset a Git config is not enough.

Comment: Every version of this question, including [the first one](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/74250750/1) used `https`. Are you trying to say that the problem is the OP's capitalization?

Comment: @Nike Yes, capitalization on the domain name `github.com`.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, you may need to check whether your proxy configuration is consistent with the computer's proxy configuration and then update the github proxy configuration via the command line or configuration file;

1. check your computer agent configuration, if you do not need him can be turned off

> Checking your computer's agent configuration can be done directly in the computer Settings search

2. Go to set github proxy configuration

> You can specify it directly from the command line `git config --global http.proxy`;
>
> or open the global proxy file for changes `git config --global --edit` The configuration file ends with.gitconfig in the user
> directory